# Basin of attraction of gradient flow

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, stability, gradient-flows

Suppose we have a compact Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, and a Morse function $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose we consider the gradient flow generated by this function, i.e. $$\dot{x_t} = - \nabla f(x_t).$$

By Morse theory, this flow will converge to a critical point of $f$, and only local minima of $f$ will have basins of attraction with positive volume. How does one go about estimating the actual volume of these basins in terms of $f$ or its derivatives?

Comment: Just a remark: any closed manifold will admit a morse function with one minimum. The volume of the basin is the total volume of the manifold. The function can be chosen arbitrarily small in the $C^k$ sense.

Comment: Though of course one can normalize by introducing things like $(\max f - \min f)^{-1}$ in the expressions.